# Create COM interface returning a pointer that is marshalled as IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, midl

I want to declare a COM Interface in MIDL that allows for returning a pointer (like in the `ID3D11Blob`). I understand that pointers are a special thing in COM because of the stubs generated for RPC calls. I do not need RPC, but only want to access the COM server from C#. The question is: can I declare the interface in such a way that the C# stub returns an `IntPtr`? I have tried to add `[local]` to enable `void` pointers, but that does not suffice.

The interface should look in MIDL like

```
[local] void *PeekData(void)
```

and in C# like

```
IntPtr PeekData()
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

**Edit:** To rephrase the question: Why is

```
HRESULT GetData([in, out, size_is(*size)] BYTE data[], [in, out] ULONG *size);
```

becoming

```
void GetData(ref byte, ref uint)
```

and how can I avoid the first parameter becoming a single `byte` in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes wrong because you imported the COM server declarations from a *type library*.  Type libraries were originally designed to support a sub-set of COM originally called "OLE Automation".  Which *restricts* the kind of types you can use for method arguments.  In particular, raw pointers are *not* permitted.  An array must be declared as a SAFEARRAY.  Which ensures that the caller can always index an array safely, safe arrays have extra metadata that describes the rank and the lower/upper bounds of the array.

The [size_is] attribute is only understood by MIDL, it is used to create the proxy and the stub for the interface.  Knowing how many elements the array contains is also important when it needs to be copied into an interop packet that's sent on the wire to the stub.

Since type libraries don't support a declaration like this, the [size_is] attribute is stripped and the type library importer only sees BYTE*.  Which is ambiguous, that can be a byte passed by reference or it can be a pointer to an array of bytes.  The importer chooses the former since it has no hope of making an array work, it doesn't know the size of the array.  So you get `ref byte`.

To fix this issue, you have to alter the import library so you can provide the proper declaration of the method.  Which requires the [MarshalAs] attribute to declare the byte[] argument an LPArray with the SizeParamIndex property set so you can tell the CLR that the array size is determined by the *size* argument.  There are two basic ways to go about it:

- Decompile the interop library with ildasm.exe, modify the .il file and put it back together with ilasm.exe.  You'd use a sample C# declaration that you look at with ildasm.exe to know how to edit the IL.  This is the approach that [Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbc969t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Use a good decompiler that can decompile IL back to C#.  Reflector and ILSpy are popular.  Copy/paste the generated code into a source file of your project and edit the method, applying the [MarshalAs] attribute.  Advantage is that editing is easier and you no longer have a dependency on the interop library anymore.

In either case, you want to make sure that the COM server is stable so you don't have to do this very often.  If it is not then modifying the server itself is highly recommended, use a safe array.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was in the process of deciding whether `SAFEARRAY` would be the better solution. With your details, I think this is the way to go. I really do not like the idea of tinkering around with the IL although this is explicitly mentioned as possible solution on MSDN...

Comment: Just one other thing I found out: It seems that the tlb import in C# produces an `IntPtr` if the return value is not typed (i.e. it must be `void *`) and has the `[local, unique]` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.110).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor2: This is the default behaviour for C-style arrays. One can avoid that by using `SAFEARRAY`s.

Comment: Hi, glad you found your answer. Please could you extract the relevant information from the link for other people trying to find out the same problem. Additionally, could you please link to the English version rather than the German version? :)